# Is there a way to announce Reminders?

Tags: ios, reminders

I know that there’s an option to announce calls. Is there any way to automatically announce Reminders at the time for which  they’re set? I’ve looked around, but couldn’t seem to find anything that would make that possible. (Though there may be and I’m just not aware of it.) Any assistance would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in your settings: `Accessibility` -> `Voice Over` -> `Always Speak Notifications`.